# Rails: Get timezone offset name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

In Ruby or Rails, given a timezone identifier like `America/Los_Angeles`, I see how I can get the specific timezone offset abbreviation like PDT:

```rb
Time.current.in_time_zone('America/Los_Angeles').zone
=> "PDT"

Time.now.in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles").strftime('%Z')
=> "PDT"

Time.now.in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles").strftime('%z')
=> "-0700"
```

And even a friendly name for the timezone itself:

```rb
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.key('America/Los_Angeles')
=> "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

But how can I get a string like `Pacific Daylight Time` instead of just `PDT` to represent the full timezone offset name for a specific date?

Input: `America/Los_Angeles` and a specific date or datetime

Desired Output: `Pacific Daylight Time`

Comment: AFAIK Currently there is no way to get full form of zone. you may need to add your own logic to do that.

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ - list of available abbreviated zones with full name

Answer (score 3):

Short story: ~for some reason,~ (as @bata [mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63846769/299774) the abbreviations are not unique so this might be a reason for no official abbreviation-human friendly name mapping) The standard seems not to support it. You might need to implement this mapping yourself. But read on if you want to get some pointers why it might not be that easy.

So... this was an interesting rabbit hole to fall into...

## Which gems are used and where do they get the info from

[ActiveSupport uses tzinfo gem for that](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/activesupport.gemspec#L37) which in turn uses tz-info gem. `tz-info` says it [uses one of two data sources](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/blob/c257b95d89a62516076543ccac6fd2ca2341dc79/README.md#L13:L17):

- zoneinfo directory in the Unix like system
- TZInfo::Data

Rails' Gemfile template [confirms that TZInfo data is used on window](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/352126936defaaeca00c23d64b15f6e464304f07/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Gemfile.tt#L78)

At first I thought there might be a PR opportunity to contribute to a popular gem. [Quick search suggests](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo-data/search?p=2&q=PDT&unscoped_q=PDT) that there's no mapping of `PDT` to any "human friendly form".

## Looking at `unix`'s `zoneinfo` database

```
$ cat /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
TZif2H*ˉ#pa&t\؀Ðݩ޾߉iip~KIR^-)4GJQ',3qo_O?/v( fe HG *)
                                                     x                                                   
                                                       q(a'Q                                             
A       0C      ΐ

௠
 #j$5 %J& '*'))6 "S      54+ !"V
eGYe턠g';gfiiHjke lmvG noV) pq6: XX YZ [޵\ ]^d _y`Mޠab-cgwdE G-Gӵ I                                      
                                ros tOt v8vxx͠yz{f|~}H~^s*&                                               
                                                         LMTPDTPSTPWTPPTTZif2^H*ˉ#pa&t\؀Ðݩ޾߉iip~KIR^-)4GJQ',3qo_O?/v( fe HG *)
                    x
                      q(a'Q
A       0C      ΐ

௠
 #j$5 %J& '*'))6 "S      54+ !"V
eGYe턠g';gfiiHjke lmvG noV) pq6: XX YZ [޵\ ]^d _y`Mޠab-cgwdE G-Gӵ I                                      
                                ros tOt v8vxx͠yz{f|~}H~^s*&                                               
                                                         LMTPDTPSTPWTPPT                                 
PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
```

Looks like a binary file...

```
$ strings /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
TZif2
 v+ !
 2s$
3Gt 4S
5'V 62
mvG n
oV) p
TZif2
 v+
3Gt
5'V
mvG
oV)
PST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0
```

Hmm. Whatever each of those means, there seems to be no "human friendly" name for this TZ.

More digging for `unix tzinfo` format, and there's apparently a `zic` and `zdump` tool

```
$ zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles  Thu Sep 10 03:07:49 2020 PDT
```

Not very useful...

```
$ zic /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
"/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles", line 1: line too long
```

Ugh.

But reading the `manpages` for one of those tools I've found out that `timezoneinfo` is an official RFC 8536. I'm not great at reading those, but in the format there's header (with version only) and

- [data block](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8536#section-3.2) (check it out, apparently it stores all historical changes for the TZ)
- [footer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8536#section-3.3) which seems to contain the PDT strings and alike, and nowhere is mentioned a possibility to provide "friendly" name.

If you have hard times reading an RFC, it looks like the `tzinfo-data` gem tries to reproduce the same data for system that does not include `tzinfo` databases (i.e. Windows):

https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo-data/blob/4ab39f022f5537b97eed133c1169f9ace3a82e2b/lib/tzinfo/data/definitions/PST8PDT.rb

```rb
          timezone 'America/Los_Angeles' do |tz|
            tz.offset :o0, -28378, 0, :LMT
            tz.offset :o1, -28800, 0, :PST
            tz.offset :o2, -28800, 3600, :PDT
            tz.offset :o3, -28800, 3600, :PWT
            tz.offset :o4, -28800, 3600, :PPT
            
            tz.transition 1883, 11, :o1, -2717640000, 7227400, 3
            tz.transition 1918, 3, :o2, -1633269600, 29060207, 12
            tz.transition 1918, 10, :o1, -1615129200, 19375151, 8
            tz.transition 1919, 3, :o2, -1601820000, 29064575, 12
            tz.transition 1919, 10, :o1, -1583679600, 19378063, 8
            tz.transition 1942, 2, :o3, -880207200, 29164799, 12
            # ... [cut!]
```

Here's `offset` method definition: https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/blob/f361d7d0b859ba5b91d30ffd6b66c3c59f90e969/lib/tzinfo/format2/timezone_definer.rb#L37:L59 (at least I think this is it, you never know until you run the code in ruby)

As you can see, no daylight saving time has `:LMT` and `:PST` abbreviations.

And here is the `transition` method https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/blob/8c549373736a7873e18bb787b818d8786591e5e5/lib/tzinfo/format1/timezone_definer.rb#L30:L61

Feel free to explore more on your own. But it looks like *each and every one* transition from DST and back is supposed to be present in the `tzinfo`. And LA seems to have stuff planned until 2060. That's actually interesting if you'll get TZ bugs related to DST if you try to calculate times after 2060?

## Last thing: Abbreviations

No idea if this is the case for `unix`'s `tzinfo` db, but in the gem they are defined locally!

It seems to be the case that `:PDT` means the same if all definitions (https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo-data/search?q=%3APDT&unscoped_q=%3APDT)

But notice that

- lib/tzinfo/data/definitions/Asia/Manila.rb defines positive offset `tz.offset :o3, 28800, 3600, :PDT`, but
- lib/tzinfo/data/definitions/America/Dawson.rb defines negative offset `tz.offset :o7, -28800, 3600, :PDT` with the same abbreviation.

What does that mean - no idea. But that might be the reason we don't have "global friendly timezone names" anywhere.

There might be errors in the database. The [official DB](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) README says:

> This database of historical local time information has several goals:
>
> - Provide a compendium of data about the history of civil time that
>   is useful even if not 100% accurate.
> - Give an idea of the variety of local time rules that have existed
>   in the past and thus may be expected in the future.
> - Test the generality of the local time rule description system.
>
> The information in the time zone data files is by no means authoritative;
> fixes and enhancements are welcome.  Please see the file CONTRIBUTING
> for details.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is a standard for abbreviations. Also, they are not unique as you see here: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/

Comment: This question is not really about abbreviations at all.